# mailgun and curl: should i use private or public api key

Tags: ruby, api, mailgun

Malign provides a public apikey and a private api key.
Which one should I use for a curl request like:

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages \
    -F from='Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>' \
    -F to=YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME \
    -F to=bar@example.com \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Mailgun Documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-api) it should be your secret (private) API key which you can find on your [Mailgun Dashboard](https://mailgun.com/app/dashboard).